# Need to Fetch specific foreign key object product from database in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Hi everyone I am new at Django and working on e-commerce site. I create a model name category and pass it to model shop by using foreign key. In Category model I have category **Sale** and i want to fetch all products that have category sale in my landing page and rest of us in shop page. Any one please help me how  I do it?
**My model.py code is:**

```
class category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   def __str__(self):
      return self.name
class shop(models.Model):
  s_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  s_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  s_category = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
  s_artical_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**View.py:**

```
def index(request):
 prod = shop.objects.get(s_category = 4) 
 params = {'prod': prod}
 return render(request, "main/index.html", params )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `related_name` to accomplish this

```
class shop(models.Model):
   s_category = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='shop_list')
```

In **views.py**

```
def index(request):
   specific_category = category.objects.get(id=4)
   prod = category.shop_list.all() #use related_name here
   params = {'prod': prod}
   return render(request, "main/index.html", params )
```

**Hint**: your classes names should follow the UpperCaseCamelCase convention so it should be `Shop, Category`

Answer (score 0):

`s_category` is a `category` instance, you can't pass a category id. First get the category object for "Sale" i.e.

```
sale_category = category.objects.get(pk=4)
```

then simply use

```
prod = sale_category.shop_set.all()
```

As a side note, try to use [PEP-8 compliant class names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names). The way you name your classes is confusing